# Can't display a text file loaded in a list in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program to help me understand how to read and write a text file.  I understand the basic ideas of it but when I try to put them into a module I can't get it to work and get the TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list in line 63, in printData with open(a) as f:  Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
    ### Subprogram getData(fn)
    #   This will load the string into a list

    def getData(fn):
        #   Opens the file and enables read
        with open(fn, "r") as ins:
            #   Creates the list to load the string
            list = []
            for line in ins:
                #   Appends the string into the list
                list.append(line)
        return list

    # ==============================================================================

    ### Subprogram printData(a)
    #   Displays the string 

    def printData(a):
        #   Opens the file
        with open(a) as f:
            for line in f:
                #   Displays the content of the string
                print(line, end = "")

    # ==============================================================================

    def main():
        #   Declare text[] and array
        text = []
        #   Assigns the fileName to data.txt
        fileName = "data.txt"

        #   Calls saveDate() and assigns the string
        saveData(fileName, "This is a test")
        #   Calls getData()
        textIn = getData(fileName)
        #   Calls printData()
        printData(textIn)

    main()
```

Comment: saveData is missing

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the open file method but your filename is a list instead of a string so you get an error. In your get data method you create a list of strings, perhaps you meant to open a file with one of those names. Either way, the filename can't be a list.

Comment: @ Cary.  Thank you.  The advise you and Moe a gave me really helped me understand what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Please up vote and/or accept answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `getData()` method returns a `list` which then you pass it to `printData()` which expects a file and not a `list`. That's why you are getting `TypeError` you need to change `printData`() to the following:

```
def printData(a):
    for line in a:
        #   Displays the content of the string
        print(line, end = "")
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  That makes a lot more sense to me.  I'm just learning python and it really helps having someone explain things when I get confused.

Comment: Hey Mike. In the future, if you get any error or simply get stuck, remember to `print` everything you can. Then you will see the output and the type of each variable.

Answer (score 0):

In `printData(a)`, a is supposed to be a list not a file, so remove the `with open(a) as f:` line from printData or pass the file to the function `printData` not the list returned by `getData`

Comment: Thank you.  I really do appreciate the help.  Everyone has helped me understand what I was doing wrong.